# Creating a heatmap for differential gene expression using heatmap.2

Tags: r, heatmap

I am trying to create a heat map of different genes and keep running into the issue that my data is not being read as numeric. I think this is because the first column is gene names and the next 6 are the values. I have tried as.matrix, as.numeric, & melt to get it to work, and I haven't been successful yet. Sample code would look like the following (I think).
`dat = (gene = c("gene1" , "gene2" , "gene3" , "gene4") , sample1 = c(1.3, -.6, .05, .69), sample2 = c(1.8,.05,-.98, .42))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `?gplots::heatmap.2()` it is expecting a matrix with only numeric values, but when you do something like:

```r
matrix(
  c(
    gene = c("gene1" , "gene2" , "gene3" , "gene4") ,
    sample1 = c(1.3,-.6, .05, .69),
    sample2 = c(1.8, .05, -.98, .42)
  ),
  nrow = 4
)
#>      [,1]    [,2]   [,3]   
#> [1,] "gene1" "1.3"  "1.8"  
#> [2,] "gene2" "-0.6" "0.05" 
#> [3,] "gene3" "0.05" "-0.98"
#> [4,] "gene4" "0.69" "0.42"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

you can see that all values are characters. As you suspected, this is because the first column is text, so if we remove it, we do get a numeric matrix:

```r
matrix(
  c(
    sample1 = c(1.3,-.6, .05, .69),
    sample2 = c(1.8, .05, -.98, .42)
  ),
  nrow = 4
)
#>       [,1]  [,2]
#> [1,]  1.30  1.80
#> [2,] -0.60  0.05
#> [3,]  0.05 -0.98
#> [4,]  0.69  0.42
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

My preferred solution however is to keep these values in a dataframe:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  gene = c("gene1" , "gene2" , "gene3" , "gene4") ,
  sample1 = c(1.3,-.6, .05, .69),
  sample2 = c(1.8, .05, -.98, .42)
)

dat
#>    gene sample1 sample2
#> 1 gene1    1.30    1.80
#> 2 gene2   -0.60    0.05
#> 3 gene3    0.05   -0.98
#> 4 gene4    0.69    0.42
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Dataframes can store values of different classes in different columns, so you `sample*` variables are not converted into characters.

To get this back into a matrix, you subset your dataframe and use `as.matrix()`. Here is an example using `dplyr` for subsetting:

```r
library(dplyr)

gplots::heatmap.2(
  dat %>% select(-gene) %>% as.matrix()
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: When I run it, I am getting random number on the right side of my heat map, it works like yours aside from that. Reading the r help page has not been useful for me in identifying the issue or command to fix - do you know what that is?